# How do I record a click to change the content on the next page with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know php or any backend type of code. I don't know if I'm asking this properly, apologies if I'm not, but what I want to happen is:

User clicks on the div/link to a page.
Javascript records the information on that div
and updates the linked page with that information
from the div that was previously clicked.
Somehow make this happen using only javascript or jquery?

I thought about just reloading the page, but that refreshes the whole page including the information gathered from the javascript click variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with cookies (providing the end user has cookies enabled on their browser) or even better you could use HTML5 Local Storage (see below) which is more secure.

```
// set your variable 
localStorage.setItem("somevariable", "something to store");

// retrieve your variable
localStorage.getItem("somevariable");
```

Comment: Wow, this is so cool! I had no idea html5 was capable of this!

Comment: +1 for letting us know the power of HTML5 here. By the way, I am curious to know where these variables are stored and whats the scope?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this, by handle url:

```
<a href="?click=true">Click</a>
```

JSFiddle don't support it, so you can copy the code on your native computer and run it.
By the way, if your need just record a parameter such as **page number \ userName** URL is the most simply method, but if you want to record a list of table data. Maybe `localstorage` or `cookie` be fit for you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cant achieve much with only Javascript/JQuery. So, sooner or later, you will have to incorporate PHP or any other server side processing mechanism.

However, to solve the current problem what you can do is to set a query string parameter on the current page. For example 'www.myurl.com/nextpage?clicked=true'. Here, `clicked=true` signifies that the user has clicked your particular div/link. On the next page read the query string `clicked` and process accordingly.

To read the query string on next page:
Option 1)
Use jQuery plugin [Purl (A JavaScript URL parser)](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl)

```
var queryStringParameter = $.url().param('queryStringParameter');
```

Option 2)
Write your own code to read:

```
function querySt(Key) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    KeysValues = url.split(/[\?&]+/);
    for (i = 0; i < KeysValues.length; i++) {
        KeyValue = KeysValues[i].split("=");
        if (KeyValue[0] == Key) {
            return KeyValue[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for Todds original suggestion and NiSay for elaborating on this.  If you are just checking to see which button was clicked then their suggestion is easier than what I suggested.

Comment: Yeah, I needed to grab the album cover, song name, and band name to display on the the next page.